# How to dynamically resize a Matplotlib figure when embedded in a custom QtWidget with QtDesigner and PySide6?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside6, qtwidgets

I am facing the following issue:

I have constructed my project as follow:

```
   ¬project
      ¬ uis  (contains all guis and widgets)
      ¬ python scripts
```

I have designed a GUI with QtDesigner and used a QWidget to embed a matplolib pyplot. I first tried to promote a custom MplWidget (in a mplwidget.py module), but due to the conversion from the ui to python code, the line linking the library could was:

`from mplwidget import MplWidget` while the right call would be: `from project.uis.mplwidget import MplWidget`  however I cannot overwrite that transcripted python file as I am still developping the gui.

I have progress by overwriting the QWidget in my gui by a MplWidget in my main script.
I am able to plot some data using this custom MplWidget, but the size is fixed.

Is there anyway to allow a dynamic resize using the parents?

My main piece of code is:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from project.uis.ui_QTplotStrokeProfileLayout import Ui_StrokeProfilePlot
from project.uis.mplwidget import MplWidget,MplCanvas
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication,QMainWindow,QWidget)


class QTplotStrokeProfileLayout(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QTplotStrokeProfileLayout, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_StrokeProfilePlot()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # replace QWidet to MplWidget
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget = MplWidget(self.ui.frame)       

        # plot some data
        x=range(0, 10)
        y=range(0, 20, 2)
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.ax.plot(x,y)
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.draw()
        
        # bind push button
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_data)       
        

    def plot_data(self):
        x=range(0, 10)
        y=range(0, 20, 2)
        y = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.ax.clear()
        self._line = self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.ax.plot(x,y)
        
        # setup title and axis labels 
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.ax.set_title("title")
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.ax.set_xlabel("x label")
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.ax.set_ylabel("y label")
        
        # display canvas
        self.ui.plotStrokeProfileWidget.canvas.draw()

    


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QTplotStrokeProfileLayout()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

My MplWidget is defined as follow:

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import (
    FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,FigureCanvasQTAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(width, height),dpi=dpi)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.ax.set_title("title")
        self.ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("ylabel")
        



# Matplotlib widget
class MplWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)   # Inherit from QWidget
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()                  # Create canvas object
        self.vbl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()         # Set box for plotting
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbl.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)) # add a toolbar
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)

        self.resize(1000,300)  # resize needed to have a visible plot
        self.vbl.setSizeConstraint
```

And finally, my compiled gui is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'QTplotStrokeProfileLayout.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.3.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QHeaderView,
    QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSizePolicy,
    QStatusBar, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget)

class Ui_StrokeProfilePlot(object):
    def setupUi(self, StrokeProfilePlot):
        if not StrokeProfilePlot.objectName():
            StrokeProfilePlot.setObjectName(u"StrokeProfilePlot")
        StrokeProfilePlot.resize(1235, 912)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(StrokeProfilePlot)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName(u"treeWidget")
        self.treeWidget.setMaximumSize(QSize(300, 16777215))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.plotStrokeProfileWidget = QWidget(self.frame)
        self.plotStrokeProfileWidget.setObjectName(u"plotStrokeProfileWidget")
        self.plotStrokeProfileWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(30, 30))
        self.plotStrokeProfileWidget.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(55, 255, 128);")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.plotStrokeProfileWidget)

        self.widget = QWidget(self.frame)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        self.widget.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(140, 140, 255);")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.widget)


        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)


        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        StrokeProfilePlot.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(StrokeProfilePlot)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1235, 22))
        StrokeProfilePlot.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(StrokeProfilePlot)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        StrokeProfilePlot.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(StrokeProfilePlot)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StrokeProfilePlot)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, StrokeProfilePlot):
        StrokeProfilePlot.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("StrokeProfilePlot", u"MainWindow", None))
        ___qtreewidgetitem = self.treeWidget.headerItem()
        ___qtreewidgetitem.setText(2, QCoreApplication.translate("StrokeProfilePlot", u"New Column", None));
        ___qtreewidgetitem.setText(1, QCoreApplication.translate("StrokeProfilePlot", u"test", None));
        ___qtreewidgetitem.setText(0, QCoreApplication.translate("StrokeProfilePlot", u"1", None));
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("StrokeProfilePlot", u"PushButton", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I went back to the widget promotion and added the full path of the mplwidget.py module as the header in the Qtdesigner.

The code generation now generate the line :
`from  project.uis.mplwidget import MplWidget`
There is no more need to overwrite the QWidget (because it has been promoted)
and the Matplotlib figure now can be dynamically resized as I strech the main window